# Google Sheets: copy a sheet to build an archive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got a simple script that creates a copy of a sheet named 'Current'. A time-driven trigger has been set up to run the script on a quarterly basis, the purpose of which is to build an archive of historical data.

This works okay, but there are two changes that I would like to make to the script and would appreciate some help.

**Queries:**

1. Can the date in the name of the copied sheet be output as a quarter (format: QQyy e.g. Q117)?
2. Can each newly copied sheet be made to directly follow the 'Current' sheet so that the archive begins with the newest copied sheet first?
3. The 'Current' sheet contains alternating colours, but they aren't copied over. Note: the alternating colours are transferred if I manually create a duplicate of the sheet. Am I missing something? Can anyone confirm why this is happening please?

.

```
function copySheet() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Current').copyTo(ss);
var Name = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "MMMyy");
sheet.setName(Name);
}
```

Comment: For Item 1. take a look at [Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the sheets from being copied to the end you can use duplicate function from Spreadsheet object to add the sheet next to the current active sheet

Give this function a try.

```
function duplicate()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.getSheetByName('LogSheet').activate()
  var sheet = ss.duplicateActiveSheet();
  var dt = new Date()
  var Name
  var month = dt.getMonth()
  var year = Utilities.formatDate(dt, "GMT", "yy");
  switch (month) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
      Name = "Q1"+year
      break;
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
      Name = "Q2"+year
      break;
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
      Name = "Q3"+year
      break;
    case 10:
    case 11:
    case 12:
      Name = "Q4" + year
      break;
    default:
      Name = "??" + year
  }    
sheet.setName(Name);
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Very nice indeed! Solves all of my problems and works beautifully. Thank you very much @Jagannathan Alagurajan